# Send Data from React JS Form to Back Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, fetch-api

I created a **react, express app** and then created a simple form in React app that accepts name and age and on submit the form data is supposed  to go to backend express app and console log there but I can not access the form input data in my backend express.On submit I get this **{"message":"Hello World"}** logged in my console of react page.

```
//express app.js

const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');


const app = express()
app.use(cors())
app.use(express.urlencoded())

app.use(express.json())

app.use("/",(req,res)=>{
    res.json({ message: "Hello World" });
    
})



app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    const { fullname, age } = req.body;
    console.log(fullname, age);
    res.send('Form submitted successfully');
  });

app.listen(5000,()=>{console.log("http://localhost:5000");})
```

My login react app:

```
import React from "react";

export default function App(){

  function submitHandler(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    const fullname = e.target.elements.fullname.value;
    const age = e.target.elements.age.value;
    fetch('http://localhost:5000/', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify({ fullname, age })
    })
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
    });
}
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
        <input type="text" name="fullname" id="" placeholder="Name:" />
        <input type="number" name="age" id="" placeholder="age" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    </div>
  );

}
```

**Help me get the form input data in express app so that I can later store it in mongodb**

Comment: Remove res.json({ message: "Hello World" }); in middleware. Because middleware will be executed before the route handler. Don't send the response from the middleware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must replace app.use with app.get

```
app.get("/",(req,res)=>{
    res.json({ message: "Hello World" });
})
```

[see documentation of app.use](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html)

Comment: Thanks bro! I was finding some big error or something like that but in the end the app.get was the problem , thanks bro you saved me